# How can i add circular seek bar in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to create the circular seek bar.The thing is, that I need a circular progress bar, where I would be able to set some values. Because my progress fill is a rainbow like gradient and i also tried many other codes and I am not able to achieve the same results using those code.after R&D i found the following link and I have seen this

https://github.com/karthikkeyan/CircularSeek

but this is in swift. i need  exactly this one functionality. but my application is in objective c. so how can i implement this in objective c.

anyone can please help me for this.
Thanks

Comment: SO is not a code writing or translation service. There is not very much code, and reading it seems rather easy. So what is your concrete problem?

Answer (score 1):

**All you need is a circular slider. Here are some libraries.**

- https://github.com/eliotfowler/EFCircularSlider
- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tb_circularslider
- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/circleslider

Comment: @user6898211 See my this answer